# SparkJava Web get(string, Route) in the type spark is not applicable

Tags: java, spark-java

I am building a simple REST API with Spark Java framework. I encountered this issue and not sure why this is happening. If it worked for

```
get("/".(req,res) -> "Hello World"
```

But did not work when I use

```
(request, response) -> {}
```

Am I missing any libraries?

My dependency looks like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
import static spark.Spark.*;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/",(request, response) -> {        
        });
        post("/transaction/add", (request, response) -> {
        });
    }
 }
```

**Error message for the method:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Route source.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Route {
    Object handle(Request arg0, Response arg1) throws Exception;
}
```

You have to return Object in lambda expression!

Answer (score 1):

```
get("/", (req,res) -> "Hello World");
```

Lambda expressions without { } return the statement, in your hello world example it returns a String, to use { } your statement needs to return what the functional interface is asking for; In spark case you need to return an object.